# How to count two related tables using Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables in my database

My first table

[image]

And my second table

[image]

I would like to count how many gold members exists and how many silver members exists...  I want to do a single count for each category... The rif can be repeated in the column but is the key to join the two tables.. I'm working with Query Builder and I would like to continue work with that. Someone can help me?

I tried with this code but didn't work

```
$count = DB::table('table1')
    ->join('table2', 'table1.rif', '=', 'table2.rif')
    ->select(DB::raw('category')
    ->count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::table('table2')
    ->join('table1', 'table2.rif', '=', 'table1.rif')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'), 'table1.category as category')
    ->groupBy('category')
    ->get();
```

If you want to count only a specific category:

```php
DB::table('table2')
    ->join('table1', 'table2.rif', '=', 'table1.rif')
    ->where('table1.category', 'Silver')
    ->count()
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#joins) for more info.

Comment: where can I specify which is silver and which is gold in that code? tanks for answer

Comment: @LaravelOscar you will have `category` and `count` for each record.

Comment: yeah, but I want a single count for each record.... one count for Silver and one count for gold

Comment: @LaravelOscar So it is, what you get instead?

Comment: I obtainen a group of numbers.. that is the count of all elements 55
30
17
1
7

Comment: I would like to obtain only the silver members count

Comment: @LaravelOscar updated my answer based on your needs.